# How to label the rows in 3x3 subplots

Tags: captions, subfloats

[image]

In the example shown below for the image attached, how can I manipulate the code to get the rows labeled?

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{10t10w125x300y3}} \quad
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{10t40w250x400y3}} \quad
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{10t100w340x500y3}} \\
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{30t10w200x400y3}} \quad
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{30t40w350x750y3}} \quad
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{30t100w550x1200y3}} \\
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{50t10w300x600y3}} \quad
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{50t40w600x1100y3}} \quad
    \subfloat[][]
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{50t100w600x1500y3}}
    \caption{Fields.}
    \label{subplots1310}
    \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to mention what kind of label you want to use for the rows (a counter? some words?). In any case, one option is to use `\parbox`es for the labels on each row (using `\raisebox` you can further control the vertical alignment for these labels). Something like the following simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \raisebox{35pt}{\parbox[b]{.1\textwidth}{labelA}}%
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{10t10w125x300y3}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{10t40w250x400y3}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{10t100w340x500y3}}\par
  \raisebox{35pt}{\parbox[b]{.1\textwidth}{labelB}}%
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{30t10w200x400y3}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{30t40w350x750y3}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{30t100w550x1200y3}}\par
  \raisebox{35pt}{\parbox[b]{.1\textwidth}{labelC}}%
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{50t10w300x600y3}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{50t40w600x1100y3}}\hfill
  \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=.28\textwidth]{50t100w600x1500y3}}
  \caption{Fields}
  \label{subplots1310}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I rotate the (label A) 270?